# Why Does the following program terminate without an error

Tags: java

Why the following program terminate without producing any thing? MyData.txt file is saved in the same directory.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class  MyIO
{
    public static void main (String[] args)  throws IOException 
    {  
        int num, square; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( "MyData.txt");      // connect a Scanner to the file

        try{    
            while(scan.hasNextInt())   // is there more data to process? 
            {
                num = scan.nextInt();
                square = num*num ;      
                System.out.println("The square of " + num + " is " + square);
            }
        } finally{
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the content of `"MyData.txt"` is? Also, why are you expecting *an error*?

Comment: you probably never enter the while loop because scan.hasNextInt() returns false

Comment: Here is the content of MyData.txt

Comment: 1 2 3

10
11
12 13 23 45
67

Comment: I am not expecting an error, I just do not expect the program to terminate without giving the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting integers from your MyData.txt file only? If the first value of the file isn't an integer, this will not enter the while loop. 
It may be possible that you've skipped a line in your code or something. Can we have a look at your MyData.txt file? (or at least an example)

Additionally, you do not need to declare the fields 'num' and 'square' outside of your loop, if you want to do some cleaning up, unless you plan on reusing them later..?